# Why can't I find files and folders in cloud server after spawning with image created by docker?

Tags: docker, gcloud

I have a `Dockerfile` in a directory on my local computer.  That directory contains files & folders that I need for my cloud server.  It's my understanding that `COPY` will make those files and folders a part of the docker image inside a newly created `/app` folder.  When I build the image with `docker build -t app:2023.01.25 .`     it builds without issues.  Then I tag and push it to Google Cloud's Container Registry with `docker tag app:2023.01.25 gcr.io/app/app:2023.01.25`   then `docker push gcr.io/app/app:2023.01.2` .  I then spawn a new server with Google's Python SDK with the new image.  I check to verify the image was used for the server, and it appears so.  So I `ssh` into the server and can't find any files.  Am I misunderstanding docker?  This is my first time using docker images.

```
# Dockerfile

FROM intel/oneapi-hpckit:devel-ubuntu20.04
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Windows cmd:

```
docker build -t app:2023.01.25 .
docker tag app:2023.01.25 gcr.io/app/app:2023.01.25
docker push gcr.io/app/app:2023.01.2
```

Comment: The image and container filesystems are inside Docker's private storage, in a format that's difficult to directly inspect.  You will not directly see the files on the remote host and that's okay.

Comment: @DavidMaze How do I know where to point my startup script when trying to access a file?  I need to run "python3 /path/to/server/server.py" after bootup.

Comment: That should be the image's `CMD`; when you `docker run` it on the remote server you don't need to say that explicitly.  (Consider making the `server.py` script executable and with a correct shebang line so you don't need to explicitly say `python3` when you run it.)